# Having trouble smoothing out elevation

Tags: rendering

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I am attempting to follow the guide [here](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/blender-relief-tutorial-getting-set-up/). I found an example of a heightmap that I liked, so I have been trying to replicate it. However, I can't seem to get rid of the terracing from the contour lines in my render. Per step six of the guide, I have exported my tiff as a 16 bit unsigned integer. I also attempted to do the map algebra function in QGIS. I'm wondering if this is the step that's giving me trouble. It seems no matter what I do, though, I can't manage to smooth out the terrain. I've tried to increase my adaptive subdivision scale from 1.0 to 3.0, but it makes my render look blurry and not detailed. I also tried raising and lowering the displacement scale to varying degrees, but the contour lines remain.

This is what I am trying to mimic
[image]

And here is my image. Notice the "steps" on the hills on the right.

[image]

Perhaps it has something to do with my heightmap?

Comment: Make sure you are interpreting the image as Non Color.

Comment: Where do I do that? I'm still trying to fumble my way around Blender.

Comment: I have the same problem. I wonder if you found a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the height image format. Here is what a ***jpg*** height image map gives:

[image]

here is what an ***OpenEXR*** height image map gives:

[image]

Comment: How do I export an OpenEXR image in Qgis? I don't see that option.

Comment: I don't know Qgis but you can do it with Krita